# How to pass parameters for list?

Tags: c#, list

Here I passed List<> as parameter but don't know to call the fields to compare and check with other.

//Check this code

```
public RankModels created(List<collection_master> col)
    {
        if (col == null)
            return null; ;
        return new RankModels()
        {
            CustomerID = col.CustomerID,--error
            AmountRecevied = col.AmountRecevied,--error
            Date_Time = col.Date_Time,
            Area = col.Area,
            AgentID = col.AgentID,
            Money_Receipt_No = col.Money_Receipt_No,
            Payment_Mode = col.Payment_Mode,
            Money_Receipt_Photo = col.Money_Receipt_Photo

        };
    }
```

Comment: You have no idea that `col` is a list ?

Comment: yes no idea how to do it?

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/collections , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx

Comment: Very simple, learn C# and work more with the list. The list is a collection which contains a lot of object. Each object has a position in list.

Comment: You shld learn List<t> before asking a qus

Comment: Please tell us what is RankModels? What you want to return? I suppose that you want to create a list of objects of RankModels and that you want to  return. However that's my assumption. So please tell us exactly what you want. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`col` is a list of `collection_master` objects. So you cannot use something like this `col.CustomerID`. You have to use indexing to get an element from your collection and then read it's properties. For instance,

```
col[0].CustomerID
```

will give you the value of `CustomerID` property of the first object that is in your list.

Comment: Yeah a bit. Although, I suggest you post another question, in order you draw the attention of users that have significant experience on web api and you get what you want.

Comment: i had wriiten  query in mysql i want change that in EF below link,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23421550/convert-query-in-mysql-to-entity-framework they closed my question y i dont know

Comment: sure thing then. What's the answer?

Comment: @sandeep I will check it out later and i will be back to you.

Answer (score 0):

your code is wrong... `col` is a list, you cannot access `collection_master`'s properties through the list.

use like:

```
CustomerID = col[0].CustomerID
```

and will work

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method like this

```
RankModels rankModel= created(col[0])
```